# How to download original ramdisk file to the computer?

Tags: linux, embedded, u-boot, ramdisk

Linux embedded, is it possible to download original ramdisk file to the computer, to get source code? Access via SFTP.

```
U-boot 1.2.0

Kernel command line: root=/dev/mtdblock3 mtdparts=spansion:0x20000(U-Boot)ro,0x10000(env1),0x10000(env2),0x2d0000@0xf0000(fware-FS),0x50000@0x7B0000(nvram),0x3B0000@0x40000(UBFI1),0x3B0000@0x3F0000(UBFI2)

7 cmdlinepart partitions found on MTD device spansion
partitions[0] = {.name = U-Boot, .offset = 0x00000000,.size = 0x00020000 (128K) }
partitions[1] = {.name = env1, .offset = 0x00020000,.size = 0x00010000 (64K) }
partitions[2] = {.name = env2, .offset = 0x00030000,.size = 0x00010000 (64K) }
partitions[3] = {.name = fware-FS, .offset = 0x000f0000,.size = 0x002d0000 (2880K) }
partitions[4] = {.name = nvram, .offset = 0x007b0000,.size = 0x00050000 (320K) }
partitions[5] = {.name = UBFI1, .offset = 0x00040000,.size = 0x003b0000 (3776K) }
partitions[6] = {.name = UBFI2, .offset = 0x003f0000,.size = 0x003b0000 (3776K) }
Creating 7 MTD partitions on "spansion":
0x00000000-0x00020000 : "U-Boot"
0x00020000-0x00030000 : "env1"
0x00030000-0x00040000 : "env2"
0x000f0000-0x003c0000 : "fware-FS"
0x007b0000-0x00800000 : "nvram"
0x00040000-0x003f0000 : "UBFI1"
0x003f0000-0x007a0000 : "UBFI2"
```

Comment: It probably is (it's possible to make a device where you can't read the original ramdisk, but it's rarely done). How to do it depends on your device, which you told us nothing about. What kind of device is it? What model? I guess the bootloader is U-Boot given the tag. What kind of storage does the device have? Note that what you'll get is not the source code, which is not present on the device, but the binary image. Do you want the initial ramdisk (initramfs) if any, the root filesystem image, or do you want the whole shebang including the kernel?

Comment: the device modem. Spansion SPI Flash storage. I want the image that store source code.

Comment: Whatever the "original ramdisk" is in your case, it won't contain source code. You'd have to contact the manufacturer to get source code. In many cases, said code isn't available in readily usable form, you'll probably need extra tools and propietary binary blobs.

Answer (score 2):

Probably yes and no.

Yes, you can probably download the image (or anything that is running on the system for that matter) - just download the "raw" data `/dev/mtdblock*`. In most cases you'll get something like a [SquashFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) image that you'll be able to mount and explore locally.

No, you are not going to get the source code in this way, with the exception of any (usually shell) scripts. Good part of the data you'll obtain like this will be compiled (and almost certainly [stripped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_%28Unix%29)) binaries.

That said, if you want to see how the boot works on the [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) level, you'll get what you want. If you want source code for the software the system is running, you're out of luck (unless it came with the hardware of course - which it actually should have). If you really want the sources, ask the system's vendor - they **must** give you the source code, otherwise they are in breach of the GPL (which is what is used for majority of software running on Linux boxen these days) - see the [GPL Violations page](http://www.gpl-violations.org/) for more details and list of lawsuits. This of course only applies to GPL (or similarly) licensed software - if you are after their proprietary software you are most likely out of luck, although on occasions it might possible to convince them to give you some access to it.

Comment: The vendor must provide the source code of any GNU GPL program on the device, including the patches that they may have made to upstream code. They are under no obligation to provide source code for programs that are not distributed under the GPL or other license that requires providing source code.

Comment: @peterph Is it possible to download a target partition with U-boot? (first copying it into RAM Load address, then from Load address to local computer via tftp).

Comment: You mean serving it by U-boot via ftp to the attached PC? I'm afraid U-boot can only *download* images like that not to serve them.

Comment: @Gilles hmm... good point well made. I guess I just got carried away by the /linux tag...